# Pressing F5 doesn't update Dolphin

Tags: filemanager

F5 no longer manually updates the file manager window.   I can press F5 multiple times and not get an update.  If I close Dolphin and reopen the files are there.

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-65-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
Memory: 15.7 GiB of RAM

I'll try the reinstall also.

Comment: Try reinstalling dolphin with `sudo apt install --reinstall dolphin`

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  also desktop if you're not using a default desktop.